# xpath selector return null in scrapy shell

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data from this url https://www.farfetch.com/shopping/men/gucci-white-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneakers-item-12889013.aspx?storeid=9359

The html looks something like this:

```html
<div class="cdb2b6" id="bannerComponents-Container">
  <p class="_41db0e _527bd9 eda00d" data-tstid="merchandiseTag">New Season</p>
  <div class="_1c3e57">
    <h1 class="_61cb2e" itemprop="brand" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
    <a href="/shopping/men/gucci/items.aspx" class="fd9e8e e484bf _4a941d f140b0" data-trk="pp_infobrd" data-tstid="cardInfo-title" itemprop="url" aria-label="Gucci">
    <span itemprop="name">Gucci</span>
    </a>
    </h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I ran `response.xpath('//div[@id="bannerComponents-Container"]/@class')` in the scrapy shell, but I all get is :

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//div[@id="bannerComponents-Container"]/@class')
Out[1]: []
```

Why? I am running into similar issues on Amazon, Ebay, etc. where my xpath selector doesnt seem to work

Comment: I tested the expression with the HTML and it does work. So the error is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: @zx482 where else do you think it could be? I am clueless on how to fix this

Comment: @darbulix, accroding to SO rules you should provide a code that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @derloopkat there is no code. I am running this in the Scrapy shell

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `headers`. Define one and get what you are after. Try the following: If you kick out the `headers` the result becomes none.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

LINK = 'https://www.farfetch.com/bd/shopping/men/gucci-white-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneakers-item-12889013.aspx?storeid=9359'

def get_item(url):
    res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    sel = Selector(res)
    name = sel.xpath('//div[@id="bannerComponents-Container"]//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
    print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_item(LINK)
```

Output:

```
Gucci
```

Comment: Why do I need to define a header? Can you explain? I tried doing the same scraping on other e-commerce platforms like Amazon, and I did not have any issues

Comment: Because it's the most simplest way to let the website know that the request is not being sent from a bot but from a real browser or human. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, you can't compare one site to another cause every site is individual and the logic implemented on one site may not bring success when applied on another.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I search for "headers web scarping", will I be able to find more information on how to make sure that the request is from a real browser/human and not a bot?